# I need help in order to create a program using the dart language to print all divisors of a( 2^63 - 1) number in crescent order

Tags: dart, integer-overflow, integer-division, large-data-volumes

hope everyone is good.
I'm a student and I'm having a really bad time with a homework.
My teacher asked me to create a program to print every divisor of a number in crescent order in less than 10 seconds using the dart language.
The problem is: He wants the divisor to be a number of about 14 characters, more precisely the number: 21,001,713,200,000.
I'm having overflow issues because this is a large number.
I really appreciate if someone could help me.

`

```
void main(){
    int a = 40;
    int aux = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < a; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            ++aux;
        }
    }
    List<int> diva = [];
    int k = 0;
    aux = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        ++aux;
        if (a % aux == 0) {
            diva.insert(k++, aux);
        }
    }
  print('${diva}');
}
```

`

Comment: Have you seen the BigInt class?  Should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't taken the BigInt classes yet, all I currently know about BigInt is the basics.
This is a question from my Mobile and Web development teacher.

Comment: If it is a homework, solve it yourself for your own good!

Comment: Yeah, I would have gave a solution if I knew it wasn't homework. :)

Comment: 10^14 is significantly less than (2^63 - 1).  You can just use a normal `int` if you use the Dart VM and not Dart for the web.

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complex.  If I asked you to find all divisors of, say, 100 without using a computer, how would you do  it?  Now translate what you did to code.  Also, why did you edit the question title?  The point of my previous comment is that an `int` for the Dart VM is a signed 64-bit value, so you should not be encountering overflow for numbers on the order of 10^14.